# JQuery: Retrieve data from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, parameters

I am 'sending' some data in a url:

```
foo.htm?mydata
```

From searching around I know that I must use something like:

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

But I am a bit perplexed by this. Could someone help me out in deciphering this at all I  simply want the end result to be placing `mydata` in a var, eg:

```
var newvar = mydata
```

Thanks heaps in advance!

Comment: Here a lot of info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: @Krycke if you actually look at the link you posted, you can tell that the function on the question here is taken from there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getParameterByName` function (I assume you got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)), is written to retrieve a query string value. This means, you can access data from the URL when it looks like this:

`yourdomain.com/index.html?key=value&anotherkey=anothervalue`

Now you can do this:

```
var firstKey = getParameterByName("key");
var secondKey = getParameterByName("anotherkey");
```

As described in your question, you **don't** have key/value pairs. If this is the case, and you only need the part *after* the `?`, simply use the following by using the [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method:

```
var newvar = document.URL.split("?")[1];
```

I do suggest you use the key/value method though, in case you want to pass on more variables in the future.

Comment: ah thanks this seems to be what I need! my url is not correct. I get this error though in my console: Uncaught ReferenceError: getParameterByName is not defined. Do I need a plugin for this?

Comment: It looks like you're calling the function before it's created; try placing the function in the code before the part where you're calling it from. There is no need for any plugin: The get getParameterByName is the function that you defined in your original post.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this library is interesting if you are in need of a lot of uri parsing:

https://github.com/medialize/URI.js